# Discord self bot returns only my account as member of a guild with multiple members

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I have created a self-bot using [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to extract members of a guild. Anytime I call `guild.members`, only my account is returned as member of the guild, although guild has multiple members. Is there a way I can retrieve all members of a guild? `fetch_members()` causes my account to be blocked temporarily.

Find code below:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import pandas as pd

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))

    def start_client(self, token):
        try:
          loop.run_until_complete(self.start(token, bot=False))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print('ready')

client = MyClient()
token = 'USER TOKEN HERE'

client.start_client(token)

guilds = client.guilds
print(guilds)

guild_f = guilds[5]
print(guild_f)

channels = guild_f.channels

print(guild_f.member_count)

members = guild_f.members
print(members)

async def getMembers(guild):
  members = await guild.fetch_members(limit=1000).flatten()
  return members

channel_members = loop.run_until_complete(getMembers(guild_f))
print(channel_members)
```

Comment: We need code...

Comment: Discord will ban self bots when they discover them

Comment: @JoshuaNixon code added. Thanks for the note about the ban. Do you know any other way I can get access to discord chat data for servers I do not manage and use in data analysis for a personal project?